# Replace date in postgres data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to clone some data from one table to another. The problem is that I have to change the date during this process.
For example change the date "2017-01-02 00:00:00.387078" to "2017-01-06 00:00:00.387078"
I'm using postgres.

Comment: `+ interval '4 day'`.

Comment: Please explain the logic for why you need to add 4 days, or if that logic would apply to all records.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff. This worked perfectly.